# Updating column values in a table based on join with another table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables called `resource` and `resource_owners`.

The `resource_owners` table contains two columns called `resource_id` and `owner_id`.

`resource_id | owner_id  |
-------------+-----------`

The `resource` table contains two relevant columns: `parentresource_id` and `id`.

`parentresource_id | id  |
-------------------+------`

`resource_owners.resource_id`, `resource.id` and `resource.parentresource_id` are all join columns between the two tables. Now what I want to do is the following:

For every row in the `resource` table, take the value in `id`, match it with a corresponding `resource_owners.resource_id`, retrieve the corresponding `resource_owners.owner_id` value (call it $owner_value), then set `resource_owners.owner_id` to $owner_value *where* `resource_owners.resource_id` equals `resource.parentresource_id`.

In conversational terms, this is what I want to do: For each resource, I want to re-assign the parent-resource's owner_id to be the resource's owner_id.

I've tried to wrap my head around this problem and it looks like I'll need two different table joins (`resource.id` with `resource_owners.resource_id` and `resource.parentresource_id` with `resource_owners.resource_id`).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is what I want even possible with a single query? I'm okay with a PostgreSQL script as well if that works better for my use case.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Might help if you stated what you're trying to accomplish in conversational text. I'm guessing maybe you want: "For each resource that has a parent-resource, re-assign its owner_id to be the owner_id of the parent resource." Also, you could provide some sample row values, and show how you would like it to look after the operation.

Comment: You nearly nailed your description. It should be: "For each resource, I want to re-assign the parent-resource's owner_id to be the resource's owner_id."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what database you are using but you should be able to accomplish using the logic below if I understood your question correctly:

`UPDATE RESOURCE_OWNER SET 
OWNER_ID = UP.OWNER_ID
FROM (SELECT rc.ID, TMP.OWNER_ID FROM (SELECT RSC.ID, ROWRS.OWNER_ID, ROWRS.RESOURCE_ID FROM RESOURCE RSC JOIN RESOURCE_OWNER ROWRS 
ON RSC.ID = ROWRS.RESOURCE_ID) TMP JOIN RESOURCE rc on rc.PARENTRESOURCE_ID = TMP.RESOURCE_ID) UP WHERE RESOURCE_OWNER.RESOURCE_ID = UP.ID;`

Comment: I'm using Postgres as my database.